# simulation with R

Tags: r, simulation, survival-analysis

I want to do survival analysis. In my dataset there are a lot of missing values and very few events. I want to generate additional data by a simulation

I have 20 patients with treatment and 20 patients with placebo.
I already have 3 events in the treatment group and I want to randomly generate 2 more events among those with treatment who have an event as NA (to have 25% event in this group) and the remaining NA will be considered as censorship.
As for the patients who have the placebo (there are 2 events), I want to generate 6 more events among those who have NA for event to have a total of 8 events.
For the patients who have the treatment I want the `time` to event to follow a normal distribution with `mean= 11`, `sd= 4.`
For patients with Placebo, I let the time follow a normal distribution with `mean=12` and `Sd=5`.
Note that the different simulations will only concern patients with NA. Another value will not be simulated for patients who already have observations for the `event` or the `time`.

```
set.seed (10)
ID<-sample(0:100,40)
Treatment<-c(rep("Treatment",20),rep("Placebo",20))
Event<- c(1,1,1,rep(NA,17),1,1,rep(NA,18))
time<-c(2,13,rep(NA,18),6,11,rep(NA,18))

data<-data.frame(ID,Treatment,Event,time)
```

Comment: Not following, but you can generate random values drawn from a normal distribution with `rnorm(n, mean, sd)`. Your data seem to be integers, so I'm not sure you want what your asking for.

Comment: This is a statistical problem, not a programming problem, so it should go on Cross Validated. In the meantime, you might consider looking into multiple imputation software (e.g., `mice` or `Amelia`), which can be used to "simulate" (as you say) or "model" values where you currently have `NA`.

Comment: @Vincent I get your point and you are right, Normally, I should do an imputation. But the objective is to generate fake data and to have a certain number of event in each group.

Comment: Check out the `fabricatr` package.

Comment: Simulating survival data in particular is a big field of research. I'd check out the `simsurv` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simsurv/index.html, it's specifically for simulating survival data. Also, when it comes to statistical questions like these, a literature search is ALWAYS a good idea to see what other researchers are doing, I would pubmed "simulating survival data"